# Redirect spam url with specific string to the homepage of my website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, spam

after a hacking attack i´ve got a few thousand spam url with "sohappy.php?xxxxxxx" in the search console and want to redirect them per .htaccess to the homepage of my website. Can anybody tell me the right syntax. Should this be done per redirct or rewrite?

Here is an sample url:
    https://www.my-website.de/sohappy.php?1je2tvq.html

Cheers Alex

Comment: There already are _millions_ of answer to exactly that question alone here on SO. None of all those questions helped you to getting started yourself? _Why not?_ And why should another answer make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you simply want to rewrite *all* requests to the base path `/sohappy`. For that you want to implement a single redirection rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?sohappy\.php$ / [R=301]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148129/discussion-on-answer-by-arkascha-redirect-spam-url-with-specific-string-to-the-h).